# How can I hide the loading screen before the website be full loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on my personal porfolio/website and I have the following bug I have been tring to fix it by myself but I don't know what else can I do.

The bug: As you can see in image 3 I have my logo (aa) and a text under it and it is still showing after the content page has been full loaded and it is showing. The aa and the under text take arround 3 seconds to hide after the loading sceen (image number 1) is hidden.

I have tried to remove the transation: 3 sec, and the bug is still there.

Any idea where the problem is and how can I fix it?

Also I dont know how is the best way to share this problem with you. I mean my code on this page in order to you can check it easily.

URL where the bug and code is DELETED

I have tried to create a mock up with the snippet tool, but without the images and all the text etc.. you cannot see the bug, becuse the mock up takes less than 1 sec to be full loaded. So then the only way I have found to show it is sharing the URL where my website is (I know it is not the best way to share a  problem) and also the JS which I am useing to hidden the loading screen.

Thanks

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById('content').className = '';
    });
  }
}
```

If you know another way to share it with you let me know.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `display: none`? I should help the children elements to stop loading.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the transition? 
`* {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}`
Try negating that universal selector `*` with a rule on that `img` element  (e.g: `#load img {transition: none;}`) and evaluate the results you get

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yes that is the problem. I had created another class with: -moz-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;     -o-transition: color 0 ease-in !important;     transition: none !important; 

However it  doesn't work. 

But you can see the answer to this bug below  

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#load.notransation {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

... will fix it.

What's going on is that the loader gets hidden too late. By using a negative `z-index` you make sure that when the content loads, it loads above the loader, so it no longer matters that it's hidden too late.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding!